# How to fix syntax errors due to colon after else statement?

Tags: python, ipython

I don't see any syntax error, do you? The error appears only in ipython, no errors if executed as python script.

$ ipython

```
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.                            

In [1]: x=None                                    

In [2]: if x==42: 
   ...:     print('') 
   ...:                                           

In [3]: else: 
   ...:     pass                                  
  File "<ipython-input-3-9c0a60a8fb6c>", line 1
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This looks like it's in iPython. You don't span a block of code across multiple inputs in iPython.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> one time more than you should have. The `else` block should be immediately after the `if` block. What you have now is an `else` with no `if`.

```
In [2]: if x==42: 
   ...:     print('') 
   ...: else:
   ...:     pass
```

Comment: Right. With that [enter], the `if` statement is terminated and executed. There's no way for the interactive interpreter to know there's any `else` coming.